# Using shared mutable state inside a spark streaming transformation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, ignite

Is there any way to have a shared mutable state inside an apache spark transformation? I know about the mapWithState operation but it's giving you a state partitioned by a key and this doesn't work for me, because I have the following case:

I have a state with the structure: deviceId : [userId : internalUserId]. So the key in the mapWithState will be the deviceId, but as one user can use more than 1 device I also need to access a flat map of that state: userId: internalUserId. And unfortunately this is not possible with the spark streaming state.

I researched a lot about this and the only thing I found for a shared state was apache ignite. The problem is that it lies on the Rdd abstraction which can only be invoked by the driver and it can't be used in a spark transformation. So it's mainly useful for sharing state between multiple applications.

So does anyone face such a problem and is it possible to be solved with spark or I need to think for another solution and do this logic outside spark?

Edit:

I forgot to mention that the application has a lot of anonymous users and the functionality I want to achieve is to map these users internally for our system. That means that I can't group the users by userId.

Comment: Why not just group all the data by `userId` and then you get all devices for the same user inside the same state?

Comment: Yep, I forgot to mention that the system has a lot of anonymous users and that's not possible. I edited the question.

Comment: Why do anonymous users prohibit you from grouping by user id?

Comment: Because the larger amount of the users are anonymous. I want to map the anonymous users to a real user. So it's important to have the anonymous users also grouped by device in order to know to which real user to map it(i.e. anonymous user used the device and then events from a logged in user are received, then it's logical that the events from the anonymous user are from one and the same person so I want to map it with the same id). But here comes the case that I have a real user that has been using 2 devices and I won't to be able to access the internalUserId from the second device.

Comment: Why not have an external service that can give you a real `userId` given a `deviceId`? Then you can use that `userId` with `mapWithState`.

Comment: That is actually my question. I'm not very keen on maintaining another application only for the user mapping. And if it's possible to have a shared state inside a transformation this will solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not a big Spark expert :) But if you can't use RDD abstraction in transformation (why, btw?) then you're forced to use something except Spark APIs, right?